# Reverse join on Django Multiple tables with User table

Tags: python, sql, join, django-models, django-views

I imported the User model and I am trying to get reviews but I also want the company of the user who made the review.

```
class fullcompany(models.Model):
    employees = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name='employee')
    somefields

class review(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    somefields


select review, user, company from review 
    join user on review_user_id=user_id
    join fullcompany on fullcompany_user_id = user_id
```

I tried the below and it doesn't work:

```
reviews = review.objects.prefetch_related('user', Prefetch('user__fullcompany')).order_by('-date')[:3]
```

Comment: `user__fullcompany` likely won't work because django implements a `through` model which holds the FK relationships between users and fullcompany objects. A user instance will have a `fullcompany_set` though for the related `fullcompany` objects though, so you might be able to query with that.

Comment: wait how do I do a relation after a prefetch_related()